# Why does "if" work instead of "elif" in this specific code?

Tags: python

I am trying to figure out variations to my coding problem, and have been trying to figure out what "elif" doesn't work in the second line here:

```
if year % 4 == 0:
  elif year % 100 != 0: 
    print("Leap year.")
  elif year % 100 == 0:
    if year % 400 !=0:
      print("Not leap year.")
    elif year % 400 == 0:
      print("Leap year.")
else:
  print("Not leap year.")
```

Why is it that in that second line, the code only runs if I use "if" instead of "elif" in that specific line? But in other instances, my "elif" works okay in the later parts?

Comment: `elif` is short for "else if". The "else" part implies that some previous condition must have failed in order for this one to be evaluated. What previous condition is this `elif` referring to? (hint: it's not.)

Comment: If you fixed your indentation (and added a `pass` in the resulting empty block) there wouldn't be a question at all.

Answer (score 1):

The `elif` on your second line does not work because it is not considering the `if` on line 1, since it is not the same indention level.

It is expecting another `if` statement above the `elif` that is in the same indentation level.

Answer (score 0):

The elif statement is used to specify an additional condition to be checked if the previous if or elif condition/conditions evaluate to False. In your code the elif statement appears immediately after an if statement, without any previous condition.

Example of your code that is working:

```
if year % 4 == 0 and year % 100 != 0:
    print("Leap year.")
elif year % 100 == 0:
    if year % 400 == 0:
        print("Leap year.")
    else:
        print("Not leap year.")
else:
    print("Not leap year.")
```